# I have an csv output for 100 weeks [2019 - 2020], i want an single output for each week & year

Tags: python, pandas

my output csv includes

//final_file.csv

```
week | candidate_id | details
201901 | 1 | xyz
201903| 2|xyz
```

i want single output files for each week of 2019 and 2020

```
201901.csv,
201903.csv
```

Comment: please recommend a FOR loop for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below (*replace `path\to_folder` by your system path to the folder where you want to write the files*)

```
weeks = df['week'].unique()
for week in weeks:
    df[df['week'].eq(week)].to_csv(f"path\to_folder\{week}.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

use `groupby` to split DataFrame by group.

```py
for week, group in df.groupby('week'):
    filename = f'{week}.csv'
    group.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```